# how to position an element right below an "absolute" div?

Tags: html, css

I have an absolutely positioned div, it takes 90% of the page, I positioned it absolutely cuz I want it to start from the right of the page (float right didn't seem to work for some reason)..

now I have other elements I want to place below that absolute div. .how do I do that? do I have absolute position those too? I hate that, it feels too messy..

```
 <div id="banner">
 <h3>title</h3>
 <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph</p>
 </div>

 <p>paragraph below the div</p>
```

css:

```
 #banner {
 background: #EBC841;
 width: 90%;
 padding: 30px 10px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 }
```

right now the paragraph is on that small space on left of the div.. I want it to be below it.. how do I do that?

Comment: If there's a way to make the div start from the right of the page without the position absolute thing that would be even better I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using absolute positioning on the div, you can add a margin-left value of 10%, which will position the div in the same place and allow the other content to display below the div and not be obscured by it: http://jsfiddle.net/FQYhk/1/

```
    #banner {
      background: #EBC841;
      width: 90%;
      margin-left: 10%;
      padding: 30px 10px;
    }
```

Comment: yup, that did It too! Thank you!